# How to activate mail application (built in in iPhone) through programming?

Tags: iphone, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

how to activate mail application (built in in iphone) through programming. I want to quit 
my project also?

Answer (score 2):

I can't really be sure by the wording of your question, but it seems like you want to send mail without leaving your application.

In the 3.0 SDK you have access to MFMailComposeViewController, which will bring up a mail window and allow you to send mail while remaining in your application.

From the Apple Docs:

> The MFMailComposeViewController class provides a standard interface that manages the editing and sending an email message. You can use this view controller to display a standard email view inside your application and populate the fields of that view with initial values, such as the subject, email recipients, body text, and attachments. The user can edit the initial contents you specify and choose to send the email or cancel the operation.
>
> Using this interface does not guarantee immediate delivery of the corresponding email message. The user may cancel the creation of the message, and if the user does choose to send the message, the message is only queued in the Mail application outbox. This allows you to generate emails even in situations where the user does not have network access, such as in airplane mode. This interface does not provide a way for you to verify whether emails were actually sent.
>
> Before using this class, you must always check to see if the current device is configured to send email at all using the canSendMail method. If the user’s device is not set up for the delivery of email, you can notify the user or simply disable the email dispatch features in your application. You should not attempt to use this interface if the canSendMail method returns NO.
>
> To display the view managed by this view controller, you can use any of the standard techniques for displaying view controllers. However, the most common way to present this interface is do so modally using the presentModalViewController:animated: method. Figure 1 shows the view that is displayed when you present the mail composition interface, with some of the fields already filled in. For more information on displaying the views associated with view controllers, see View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to:

```
NSString *_recipient = @"someone@email.com";
NSURL *_mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=My Subject", _recipient]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_mailURL];
```

will open the Mail app and create a new message with the subject "My Subject" and the recipient `someone@email.com`. Just modify this with other headers and content to build the message you need to send.

Comment: i checked your code.it did not open mail app in iphone and also quit my app.any frame work? clear explaination?

Comment: There must be something wrong with how you're implementing this. This is the standard way to open the Mail app. I'm not sure how this code sample could get any clearer?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can send mail from the iphone app.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:biranchi@purpletalk.com?cc=youremail@gmail.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20Biranchi!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to quit your app:

[iphone app send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494626/iphone-app-send-email/1494702#1494702)