# how to send e-mail without MFMailComposeViewController in iOS?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How to redirect to mail application from iPhone application?
I have seen in Stack Overflow  like MailComposerViewController.
They are sending email from within the iPhone application. But **I want to quit project and redirect it to in-built Mail app** Which is in iPhone?

How can I do this?

I have tried the following. Are there any frameworks required for this?

```
- (IBAction)ddd:(id)sender
{
    NSString *_recipient = @"someone@email.com";
    NSURL *_mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=My Subject", _recipient]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_mailURL];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there are plenty of stackoverflow posts on how to send e-mail without MFMailComposeViewController.  In fact, there was at least one response to [your request 16 hours earlier that would quit your app and start Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519667/how-to-activate-mail-applicationbuilt-in-in-iphone-through-programming/1519755#1519755)

Here's how I do it in my apps, copied exactly as it is:

```
-(IBAction) mailForHelp:(id)sender
{
    NSString    *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:info@BitsOnTheGo.com?subject=NumMemorize Question"];
    NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: mailURL];
}
```

Comment: i did it like 
NSString *_recipient = @"someone@email.com";
NSURL *_mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=My Subject", _recipient]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_mailURL];
but it did not give output......i created on button in which i coded above thing...

Comment: This doesn't do anything in the simulator.  On the iPhone, it should quit your app and launch Mail.