# How to add share via email option in my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a feature of sending some text  via email from my iphone app. please tell me how to proceed. plz tell the steps on how to send email from and to .
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone app send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494626/iphone-app-send-email)

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the [documentation for the `MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: There is also sample code listed under "Related sample code" at that link.

Answer (score 1):

A very cool, and easy way to gain this and other share features is to add [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/).  It take 5 minutes to setup and lets you add Twitter, Facebook and others.