# Iphone send email from application

Tags: iphone, email

I need to be able to send emails from within the application I am developing.

Using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mail@mail.com"]] , the email application opens and the user can't go back to the main application.

Is there a way I can send the user back to the application after they are done sending emails ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone app send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494626/iphone-app-send-email)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at MFMailComposeViewController class (requires MessageUI.framework) - it provides you with standard UI to create and send mails from inside of your application

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can include a mail composer in your application.

Look into the [MFMessageComposer class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and the MessageUI framework. It will allow you to show a Mail Composer view within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below URL;

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-send-email-with-attachments/