# Send an email from my iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, email

I know that I can use MFMailComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate to pop up email composer template with my to/from/subject settings and user can edit these settings and click send button.

Reference links:
  [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)
  [Iphone send email from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147598/iphone-send-email-from-application)
  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html

...but my requirements are different. I want to develop a form (user inquiry/feedback form) where user need not to special to/from address rather they input their details and click send button. For example, form given at http://www.connectjets.com/quote.html

Is there anyway such that the mail composer template won't pop up and I can send an email directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a PHP-Script that handles sending email. Present a form from within your app and then post that data to this PHP script using `NSURLConnection`. Then you don't need to use the mail composer...

Comment: Thanks. I have never used PHP script. It would be great if you could provide some sample code. I am wondering why can't I directly do it from my application? Can't I add sending email code (that I suppose to put in PHP script) in my application on Send button click event?

Comment: If you don't know PHP and don't have a webserver to run this script on, try out a SMTP library like skpsmtpmessage (http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/). It claims to provide this functionality

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the SMTP library skpsmtpmessage, but was unable to get it to send messages... I also investigated this issue fairly thoroughly, but it could not be done.

[Can I send email programmatically in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119522/can-i-send-email-programmatically-in-iphone-app)

Please let us know if you are successful with the PHP solution, it sounds like a good strategy. You should be able to then send the email server side.

Comment: Well, I am not going to implement this in PHP as our environment is setup with ASP.NET MVC. I have another idea and gonna to give a try. I will send required information to my web server - Controller on Send button click event and from there I can send an email using .NET libraries.