# Send Email in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

I am new to iphone. I am working on first app..I could design Email view by using Interface Builder. My requirement is, I have to add contact list. And choose required contact, when i clicked on To UIButton, It will be placed on Address textfield.

Finally, I can click the send UIButton, the email reach it's destination.
How can I do this? Can anyone explain it and send me proper code.

Image link is:
http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/6447/emailau.png

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code in the below link

[Problem sending email from an app with MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285597/problem-sending-email-from-an-app-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/4285751#4285751)